# Unable to get data from Arduino Bluetooth board to the PC

Tags: arduino, bluetooth

I'm trying to transmit data from my PC to an Arduino board. I'm able to see what the Arduino sends to the PC using Tera Term but I don't get any data from PC to Arduino. I've tried changing the pins and everything out there (even testing another bluetooth board). I'm using an Arduino Mega 2560.

Here is the code:

```
#include <AFMotor.h>
#include <NewPing.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define LED 52

#define RxD 17 
#define TxD 14 

SoftwareSerial blueToothSerial(RxD,TxD);

void setup() {
  blueToothSerial.begin(9600);
  blueToothSerial.println("Bluetooth On please press 1 or 0 blink LED ...");
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RxD, INPUT);
  pinMode(TxD, OUTPUT);
}

byte BluetoothData;
void loop()
{
  if (blueToothSerial.available())
  {
    BluetoothData = blueToothSerial.read();
    if(BluetoothData=='1'){ // if number 1 pressed...
      digitalWrite(LED, 1);
      blueToothSerial.println("LED  On D13 ON ! ");
    }
    if (BluetoothData=='0'){ // if number 0 pressed...
      digitalWrite(LED, 0);
      blueToothSerial.println("LED  On D13 Off ! ");
    }
  }
  delay(100); // prepare for next data...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this documentation for the [SoftwareSerial](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerial) library, pin 17 on the Arduino Mega 2560 does not support change interrupts, so it wont work with your Blutooth device. Instead choose an Rx pin listed in the documentation (e.g. 0, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15).

Also for the Arduino to receive bluetooth data the SoftwareSerial [listen](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerialListen) method should be used. Try modifying your code so that it uses this method e.g.

```
void loop()
{
  blueToothSerial.listen();
  if (blueToothSerial.available() > 0)
  {
    BluetoothData = blueToothSerial.read();
    if(BluetoothData=='1'){   // if number 1 pressed ....
      digitalWrite(LED, 1);
      blueToothSerial.println("LED  On D13 ON ! ");
    }
    if (BluetoothData=='0'){// if number 0 pressed ....
      digitalWrite(LED, 0);
      blueToothSerial.println("LED  On D13 Off ! ");
    }
  }
}
```

Note that when using listen() I don't think the call to delay() will be necessary.

Comment: I'll try that but I don't think it will solve it since I tried attaching to 14 and 15 also. I'm not writing to the Serial because I do see the blueToothSerial.println in the Tera Term but I'm not able to get the keystrokes or data in the Arduino.

Comment: Ok, give it a go because pin 17 on the Arduino Mega 2560 should definetly not be used in the scenario you have.

Comment: It didn't work, it looks like it is only one way. Could it be? It works perfect from Arduino to Tera Term but when I try to get data from Tera Term to Arduino it doesn't get any.

Comment: I think it's only working one way because the code you have does not instruct the Arduino to listen for bluetooth signals. This should explain why it only works one way i.e. from arduino to PC. See my updated answer.

Comment: It doesn't work. I thought that listen was a blocking function but it returns immediately. Do you know how I can troubleshoot to determine the source of the problem?

Comment: I'd try deploying the example included on the listen() documentation page to determine whether the board is listening out for bluetooth data correctly (i.e. via the isListening() method).